# Support team's misleading tag wiki edit

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

A few days ago, I rejected the following [edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14554889) for the [pushe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pushe) tag wiki:

> Pushe.co is a mobile "backend as a service", *baas*, platform
>   providing mobile developers with analytics services and software
>   related services like push notifications and ...
>
> To provide technical support to users, Pushe.co's support team always
>   looks for questions tagged **pushe** in stackoverflow.
>
> So in case you encounter any problem using Pushe libraries inside your
>   applications, ask your questions and tag them accordingly so our
>   support team will answer them ASAp.
>
> For more information, please refer to the documentation and website,
>   found below:
>
> [Pushe.co website](http://pushe.co)
>
> [Documentation page](http://panel.pushe.co/documentation)
>
> [Organizational website](http://ronash.co)

I don't think a tag wiki should contain phrases like "our support team" as it sounds like there is a collaboration or that space is provided for their support team. However, it got approved with 2 rejections and 3 approvals. So I made another [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14629380) to remove the second and third paragraphs but it got rejected too.

Was my action wrong? If not, what should I do next?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your action was correct. It's possible reviewers just saw a bunch of information being deleted and reached for the reject button.

Explaining that the support team actively browses the tag and that users should use it is... pointless. Of course users should use the tag for questions about that tag - talk about redundant - and no, we *don't* need to know that their support team actively browses it. If they want to do it, they should just do it.

Tag wikis are for explaining what the technology is, how it relates to Stack Overflow's scope, and how the tag should and should not be used (if it's not clear). Talking about the company and its staff is not an appropriate use of the tag wiki.

Comment: I noticed the links in there link to sites that aren't in English. Figured that's good for a meta [question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339806/linking-to-non-english-sites-in-tag-info).