# Linking to non-english sites in tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, external-links, languages

Another [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339802) mentioned the [pushe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pushe) tag.

Looking at the tag wiki, the 3 links in there all link to non-English sites, with no *"gimme an english version"* button, as far as I can find.

Since Stack Overflow is English-only, are those links really appropriate?

Sure, it links to `<tagname>.co`, but for all we know, it's just spam.

Comment: Now that I've gotten a couple of downvotes: I'd love to see a good argument for the value of these links. I won't bite ;-)

Comment: We know. You'll let your horse bite them ;)

Comment: @honk Did you just called his wolf a horse?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I was referring to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olnW4.jpg) Cerbrus had posted in his [nomination post](http://stackoverflow.com/election/8#post-40475904) on the 2016 moderator election.

Comment: Someone is stalking Cerbrus here... ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I'm doing my very best, but I haven't found out so far if he actually also has a wolf and if he cuddles it as well ;)

Answer (score 9):

Although the links are **not** spam, they are not informative or helpful for non Persian speakers, especially when there is no translation button appearing in the website; so I think they should be removed from the tag's description.

After Googling a bit about the company, I noticed that all participants on the [pushe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pushe) posts, [works for the company](https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?f_CC=10423220&trk=rr_connectedness), this seems a bit suspicious for me, I'm not sure if it's legal/ethic thing to do.

Comment: 2nd paragraph: I noticed that, too. None of the questions are particularly good, and one has some close votes. But that's not really the point of this question, of course. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus I gave my opinion on the links on the 1st paragraph, I do agree that the links shouldn't be there if they're not English, or at least, have an option to be translate.